# How to make sure BackHandler doesn't double up for the same event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, addeventlistener, event-listener

So I have the following routes:

```
<Router>
                <Scene key="root" hideNavBar>
                    <Stack key="Auth" initial={!this.state.isLoggedIn}>
                        <Scene key="Login" hideNavBar component={Login} title="Login" />
                    </Stack>
                    <Stack key="Main" initial={this.state.isLoggedIn}>
                        <Scene drawer key="NavDrawer" hideNavBar contentComponent={NavDrawer} type={ActionConst.REPLACE} panHandlers={null}>
                            <Scene key="homeTab" navBar={() => <PageHeader title='Home' />} drawerLockMode={'locked-closed'}>
                                <Scene tabs={true} tabBarComponent={ScrollableTabBar} tabBarPosition='top' lazy={true}>
                                    <Scene key="Home" hideNavBar component={Home} title={"Home"} name='Home' />
                                </Scene>
                                <Scene key="itemDescription" hideNavBar component={itemDescription} title="Item Description" back />
                            </Scene>
                            <Scene key="helpTab" navBar={() => <PageHeader title='Help' />} title="Help" drawerLockMode={'locked-closed'}>
                                <Scene>
                                    <Scene key="Help" hideNavBar component={Help} title={"Help"} />
                                </Scene>
                            </Scene>
                            <Scene key="settingTab" navBar={() => <PageHeader title='Settings' />} title="Settings" drawerLockMode={'locked-closed'}>
                                <Scene>
                                    <Scene key="Setting" hideNavBar component={Setting} title={"Setting"} />
                                </Scene>
                            </Scene>
                            <Scene key="QRTab" navBar={() => <PageHeader title='QR Scanner' />} title="QR" drawerLockMode={'locked-closed'}>
                                <Scene>
                                    <Scene key="QRScanner" hideNavBar component={QRScanner} title={"QR Scanner"} />
                                </Scene>
                            </Scene>
                        </Scene>
                    </Stack>
                </Scene>
            </Router>
```

in my NavDrawer, I have the following to handle hardware back button:

```
    handleBackButton() {
        if (Actions.currentScene === '_Home')
            this.onSignOut()
        else if (this.state.currentTab !== 'Home') { //in another tab
            this.setState({ currentTab: 'Home' })
            Actions.homeTab();
        }
        else if (Actions.currentScene === 'Login')
        {
            BackHandler.exitApp();
        }
        else{   //in home tab, siblings of Home scene
            Actions.pop();
        }
        return true;
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton);
        console.log('didmount')
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress');
        console.log('unmount')
    }
```

Now there is a problem when I am auto-logged-in, because `NavDrawer` is at the root of `Main` stack, when I close the app and open it again, it will remount 'NavDrawer` without ever unmounting it.

To further describe the scenario:

login-->NavDrawer (`componentDidMount` called) --> BackHandler added --> close app or hot reload (`componentWillUnmount` never called, BackHandler stays) --> auto login --> NavDrawer remounted (`componentDidMount` called again) --> BackHandler that listens to the same event added --> double BackHandler causing a default BackHandler triggered instead of the one I defined

So this scenario happens until I log out which unmounts `NavDrawer` and removed the handler altogether starting the listeners with clean slate. Only then everything works as expected.

Any suggestions how to handle this?

I was thinking putting `removeEventListener` in `constructor` to make sure there's no doubles, but I don't know if that will cause problems in case there isn't any handlers to remove..

UPDATE:

so I tried my solution and the one in the comment below, and it didn't work.
upon closer inspection what may have happened is that there may not be any liteners to remove that is directly related to the new "reboot", hence why our solution didn't work.

There is still, however, listener from previous reboot interfering with the current one somehow. because after further observation, I noticed that in the case of closed/reboooted app, when I am pushing a new `Scene` onto the stack, it attaches a new default listener to that `Scene`, which in the listener's stack is pushed on top of the one that I want to use.

I suspected this because once that scene attached with default listener is popped off the stack, my listener is back in business.

So.... long story short I still need a way to detect app close or reboot scenario so I can remove listener before everything is remounted without any unmounting done. OR force trigger the `componentWillUnmount` or put my `removeListener` to similar hooks when this case happens

Comment: I would do as you suggested, except I'd add `removeEventListener` to `componentDidMount` instead, prior to `addEventListener`. This would guarantee that your handler is never doubled.

Comment: the theory seems sound, but turns out it didn't work. I think there's something else going on underneath that we are unaware of. i.e. not unmounting the component doesn't mean the whole app (hence the whole route) is not rebooted,but listeners are of higher order so it's stuck in a "limbo" somehow. Because if this solution fails, that means there is no listener to remove after reload (at least not one directly connected to current reboot) but the previous unmounted (and un-removed) listener is still affecting the current one somehow..:(

Comment: Is there a hook/event you can use when the app is closed or reloaded that would allow you to do some cleanup? I know this is what you're trying to do with `componentWillUnmount`, but there has to be a way...

Comment: @Jaxx that's the thing, couldn't find one, the only possible way right now is to use AppState from react-native but it doesn't specify anything about app closing/crashing/rebooting only when it's in background mode or active. That's why I'm posting this here to see if anyone has some magical way of identifying that situation. My app only require this to update a state in my drawer so for now I'm doing a workaround using `componentWillUpdate`, but it's not ideal although it produces the same UX, it's such a hack job that I'm afraid it will cost me more hours in the future

Comment: I just don't understand why would react-native not call `componentWillUnmount` in cases of app close/reboot/crash, didmount without willunmount is just so weird to digest :(

Comment: I had the same issue, but I solved it by removing the event listener in the moment after I did the redirection. Strange that componentWillUnmount is not evoked properly ...